# android studio gives me an error : (access denied)

Tags: android-studio, react-native

*I deleted my app on phone and then I run android studio but it gives me an error like this :*

```
C:\reactnative\ProjectName\android\app\build\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out\signing-config.json (Access Denied)
```

*I didnt get this error before.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just delete the file `signing_config.json`

Run `react-native run-android` or run app from android studio again

Answer (score 1):

Run Android Studio as Administrator it will work.

Answer (score 0):

delete build folder which is placed in `C:\reactnative\ProjectName\android\app\`
 and then run your project `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

As I  was not able to even clean the  project, So I deleted the build folder manually, and build It again, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me,  there is not such a file and path in the project directory. Just I have to run Android studio as administrator and problem gone.
I use windows 10 , 64.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this error in Flutter then just run the following command in terminal

> flutter clean

the answer is given for flutter. If someone is wondering