# flutter: can't run a basic hello world program because ' Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'. '

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, gradle

I'm a total beginner to flutter and android studio and as I was trying to run a very basic hello world program I got this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\flutter\newapp\build\app\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out\signing-config.json (Access is denied)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\flutter\newapp\build\app\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out\signing-config.json (Access is denied)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I've tried `flutter clean` but that didn't work. I manually cleared cache through android studio that didn't work either. I finally rebooted my machine and that didn't work either.

I'm out of luck and solutions. Any help would be appreciated.

(running windows 10)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55371137/android-studio-gives-me-an-error-access-denied/55371287

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to the route `D:\flutter\newapp\build\app\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out\` and delete the file `signing-config.json` then run again.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Redownloading the flutter SDK, and use Microsoft VSC instead of Android Studio.Its lightweight and dosent pose much stress on your PC.

Comment: unfortunately, I can't do that because I've purchased a udemy course on flutter and the professor is using android studio so I'd like to stay in sync with her.

Comment: Nice... However what version of Flutter SDK are you using?? Did you download a stable version?

Comment: Yes it's a stable version. Flutter 1.17.5.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, the command flutter clean worked.